# WPF multiple comboboxes dynamic binding

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

I am trying to develop a project that will follow the MVVM pattern and it will load part of the UI dynamically (the dynamic UI is saved in the database-so I can load different UI in different situations). The problem that I have is that this UI has a lot of comboboxes.
So I use a content control to load the UI and in my ViewModel I have a property FiltersUI

```
<ContentControl x:Name="FiltersPanel" Content="{Binding FiltersUI}" />
```

This works excellent. 
The problem is that usually the UI has multiple comboboxes that I need to fill them from the database.
So imagine that I have UI_1 and UI_2.
The UI_1 has 3 comboboxes that I need to fill from the database and the UI_2 has 5 comboboxes with different datasources (again from database).
How I could load all the different datasources and bind them to the comboboxes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364557/wpf-combobox-with-compositecollection-selectedindex-not-sticking

Comment: I don't see how this is relevant (sorry)

Comment: @Maximus OK. Now I see your point to use the CompositeCollection as multiple datasources container. I'll try and get back to you. Thanks