# WPF add extra item to bound collection

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `ItemsControl`which have bound items. As you can see in the screenshot, those items are bound to a property and I want an extra item appear which will have totally different behaviour than the other items. How can I achieve this (preferabelly with xaml only)?

[image: Screenshot for what I want]

Comment: Are you using a MVVM architecture in your application? Anyway, there is no way to do that only in XAML since this is not View-related, but Model-related. The separation of concern dictates that this should be handled by a command in your ViewModel.

Comment: @DesterDezzods there is `CompositeCollection` but it is tricky to use when you bind `ItemsSource` to list in view model. Easiest solution would be to have collection of your items and some item of different type at the end and have 2 `DataTemplate` in `ItemsControl.Resources`, one for each `DataType`

Comment: @dkozl, I didn't know you could have 2 datasource I'll see what I can find. thanks :)

Comment: One items source with two types and two data templates

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [Composite Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection(v=vs.110).aspx). Wpf example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364557/wpf-combobox-with-compositecollection-selectedindex-not-sticking) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381859/can-you-add-an-extra-item-to-a-data-bound-itemscontrol-in-xaml?rq=1).

Based on comment, here is sample code from first example

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="All" />
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource AllBitsSource}}" />
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>
```

**Edit** - MVVM

The issue with CollectionContainer is that is does not have access to curent DataContext. StaticResource solves it

xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfApplication5"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="525" FontSize="25">

    <StackPanel Name="stk">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvsBooks" Source="{Binding Path=Books}" />
        </StackPanel.Resources>

        <ListBox>
            <ListBox.ItemsSource>
                <CompositeCollection>
                    <ListBoxItem>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Margin="5,0">Not tagged</TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                    <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsBooks}}"/>
                </CompositeCollection>
            </ListBox.ItemsSource>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

        <Button Content="Add" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

C#

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var vm = new ViewModel();
        this.stk.DataContext = vm;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //should be Command in MVVM, but this is just example to see that ObservableCollection works
        var btn = sender as Button;
        (btn.DataContext as ViewModel).Books.Add(new Book() { Name = "Book" + DateTime.Now.Second });
    }

}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        this.Books = new ObservableCollection<Book>();
        this.Books.Add(new Book() { Name = "Book 1" });
        this.Books.Add(new Book() { Name = "Book 2" });
        this.Books.Add(new Book() { Name = "Book 3" });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Book> Books { get; private set; }
}

public class Book
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> which will have totally different behaviour than the other items.

Behavior is done with styles. I will provide a listbox example which is translatable to the ItemsControl.

---

Say for example we have an `Order` class with these properties

```
public class Order
{
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public bool InProgress { get; set; }
}
```

When an order is marked as in progress (`InProgress` = `true`) we want to show red in our list box say for "Alpha" and "Omega" which are in progress:

[image]

**ListBox Xaml**

Here is the Xaml which binds to our data (how you bind is up to you) and shows how to work with [Style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style(v=vs.110).aspx)(s), [DataTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate(v=vs.110).aspx), and [DataTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Windows.DataTrigger);k(VS.XamlEditor);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5)&rd=true)(s) to achieve that:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource Orders}"
         x:Name="lbOrders">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Order}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CustomerName}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=InProgress}"
                             Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground"
                            Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

Here is the data setup in the pages's resource Xaml to do that, but it could be created in code behind:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <model:Orders x:Key="Orders">
        <model:Order CustomerName="Alpha"
                        OrderId="997"
                        InProgress="True" />
        <model:Order CustomerName="Beta"
                        OrderId="998"
                        InProgress="False" />
        <model:Order CustomerName="Omega"
                        OrderId="999"
                        InProgress="True" />
        <model:Order CustomerName="Zeta"
                        OrderId="1000"
                        InProgress="False" />
    </model:Orders>
</Window.Resources>
```

---

Now its just a question of what property your *added* item will have which will trigger a different style.